# Do I need to use authentication check for public methods?

Tags: php, security, oop, methods

In object-oriented PHP application, do I need to use `authentication` check in almost every `public` method in my application for security?

I'm worried about this vulnerability: [CWE-306: Missing Authentication for Critical Function](http://cwe.mitre.org/top25/#CWE-306)

**How anyone could call my public methods, even if I use `static` keyword?**

---

What are the requirements for this attack to succeed?

Like some another vulnerability - Like allowing PHP file uploads to my system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the article states, this won't be a problem if you structure you application properly. Whether your class has public or private methods is not the issue here, the problem is that the pathways to your application are not secured.

Your application should be structured so that it provides only a single point of entry. Any request to any file should be routed through your main file. None of your other PHP files should accessible directly. When you structure it this way, it's easy for you to apply your authentication as you would be able to examine each request that comes to your application and identify which need to be authenticated and which can be served publicly.

Have a look at this pattern : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern

Comment: I would have given this +1, were it not for the recommendation of using a front-controller to implement the solution :P

Comment: That's how I would do it, but I'm always interested in how other people approach things. Post your solution! :)

Comment: In terms of the underlying architecture I'd take a similar approach - one php include file which checks authentication (and usually also handles session mgmt and authorization) - but as an included file from the execution entry point - not acting as a router